# How is retarded Green's function related to 1D scattering coefficient?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, scattering, greens-functions

I have been reading a paper about Green's function with 1d potential barrier
https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.114.126602
Supplementary material Sec. II

$H=\hbar^2k^2/2m+V\Theta(x)$. Let's say the transmission coefficient and reflection coefficient are $t$, $r$ for right-going wave and $t'$, $r'$ for left-going wave. The scattering waves solutions are, for right-going,
$$\phi_{k_-<0}(x)=e^{ik_- x}+re^{-ik_-x}\,, \quad x<0\\
=te^{ik_+x}\,, \quad x>0$$
and, for left-going
$$\phi_{k_+>0}(x)=t'e^{ik_-x}\,, \quad x<0\\
\qquad\qquad\qquad=e^{ik_+ x}+r'e^{-ik_+x}\,, \quad x>0$$
where $E=\hbar^2k_-^2/2m=\hbar^2k_+^2/2m+V$

The retarded Green's function for a fixed energy usually are defined by
$$
G(x,x',E)=\sum_n\phi_n(x)\phi^*_n(x')/(E-E_n+i0^+)
$$
How can I get the solution of the Green's function from the scattering wave? e.g, Eq. (S17) in Supplementary material Sec. II.

Comment: The scattering states are eigenstates of the Hamiltonian. Therefore, you can just use the (scattering) wave functions in the expression of the Green's function.